# Select2 dropdown won't close at all

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2, dropdown

I have a `select` element with a few `option` elements, but the dropdown menu will not close after I open it.

I don't know why it doesn't work on my project but it works perfectly fine on a new project.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#user-selection').select2();
});
```

```html
<select id="user-selection" name="userId" style="width: 100%" required>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Am I missing something out?

Update: Changed to correct version of Select2 which made the problem go away

Comment: _(I don't know why it doesn't work on my project but it works perfectly fine on a new project.)_ Of course you're missing something out. Share more details, any console errors once it's opened, or any fiddle link with the problem visible, otherwise it's hard to debug.

Comment: I know this is a little late, but there are no errors that comes up in the console. Another thing to add on is that it is on a bootstrap Modal and I have included the dropdownparent attribute to the Select2.

Comment: Also, I am unable to recreate this problem on jsfiddle

Comment: I had the same problem. I was running select2.js version 4.0.6. I updated it to the (current) version of 4.0.8, and the problem disappeared. Try updating the version of the software, see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

This error at last version of select2, you can use the file I attached I edit focus event at select2.js

```
this.on("focus", function () {
    a.$container.addClass("select2-container--focus"), 
    a.$container.hasClass("select2-container--disabled") || a.isOpen() && (a.options.get("multiple") ? window.setTimeout(function () {
        a.open()
    }, a.options.get("ajax") ? 300 : 100) : a.open())
}),
```

from `a.isOpen() ||` to `a.isOpen() &&`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dits.cloud/js/select2.js"></script>

<select id="user-selection" name="user" style="width: 100%" required>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#user-selection').select2();
    });
</script>
```

[Edited select2.js](https://dits.cloud/js/select2.js)

Comment: Nope i downloaded the js and css files

Comment: Sir use my edited file I say that I edit it to fix the same problem